# trouble with sideloading a hasMany relationship in ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

this is ember rc1 master as of march 25, and ember-data rev 12.  i can't get a Model's hasMany to sideload - that sideloaded data doesn't materialize in the store. using the default RESTAdapter.

```
  App.AssetLinkGroup = DS.Model.extend({
      asset_links : DS.Model.hasMany('App.AssetLink')
  })
  App.AssetLink = DS.Model.extend({
      asset_link_group : DS.Model.belongsTo('App.AssetLinkGroup')
  })
```

the json i'm returning from the server for App.AssetLinkGroup.find(5) is as follows (with a lot of the basic attributes like name/date/etc removed for brevity)

```
 {
 "asset_link_group": {

      "asset_link_ids": [154,155],

      "asset_links": [
           {
                id : 154,
                "asset_link_group_id": 5
           },
           {
                id : 155,
                "asset_link_group_id": 5
           }
      ]
   }
 }
```

App.AssetLinkGroup.find(5) successfully loads the AssetLinkGroup model from the server.  but the AssetLinks don't seem to get materialized in the store.  when i try an App.AssetLink.all() .content, it shows an empty array.

furthermore if i try:

```
var algroup5 = App.AssetLinkGroup.find(5);
algroup5.get('asset_links');
```

it makes a findMany call to the server which shows me it definitely doesn't have these records in the store.

why aren't the AssetLink records materializing in the store when i load AssetLinkGroup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that the asset_links array in the JSON should be at the root level.

```
{
 "asset_link_group": {
   "asset_link_ids": [154,155]
 },
 "asset_links": [
   {
      id : 154,
      "asset_link_group_id": 5
   },
   {
       id : 155,
       "asset_link_group_id": 5
   }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: yep, misread the docs and put it asset_links at the wrong level. thanks.

Comment: Isn't there a syntax error in the answer? Shouldn't the comma after "asset_link_ids": [154, 155] actually be after the closing } for "asset_link_group" ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your adapter to sideload the records in `asset_links`? Assuming you are using `RESTAdapter`, you would do something like this:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure('App.AssetLink',
    sideloadAs: 'asset_links'
);
```

Comment: I think you have to do this stuff only if AssetLink is not evolved in an association with the "main" model you ask for.

Comment: Aha, I didn't realize that. Good catch.